# Is following proof of $\exists X \forall Y \exists Z .(X\subseteq Y \cap Z) $ valid?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, fake-proofs

I have to make or deny proof for :
$\exists X \forall Y \exists Z .(X\subseteq Y \cap Z) $

Is the proof by saying that $\emptyset \subseteq All$ and  so $X = \emptyset$
enough?

Comment: Could you state *in english* what the statement you are trying to prove is?  It sounds like you are trying to prove: There exists a set $X$ so that for every set $Y$ there exists a set $Z$ so that  $X\subseteq Y\cap Z$ which is... as you argue ... trivial.  But a bizarre statement (who cares about the $Z$?)

Comment: yeah.. It sound very trivial.. In fact, it's not mine, I found it in one exercise  book online and it just seems so easy, that I'm confused a little bit .. There is nothing more than this the exercise gave me..

Comment: Well, Sure $X=\emptyset $ will be a subset of $Y\cap Z$ for any $Y$ and any $Z$.  And it's the only such set the statement is true.  If $X$ is non empty then there is an $x \in X$ an there can exists sets $Y$ so that $x \not \in Y$ and so $X \not \subset Y$ and nor can $X\subset W\subset Y$ for any subset, $W$, of $Y$. So there can not exist any set $Z$ so that $X\subset Y\cap Z$....  I guess it's a valid excercise in concept and definitions .... but basic.  You seem to be beyond the level of such definition quiz cards.

Comment: Yeah. exactly. I must find some more difficult ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, there is no trick question.